# How to find the number of common elements between 1D array and specific index [y][x][all elements] of a 3D array?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, performance

I have found the answer how to find the number of commom elements of 1D array vs all 3D array.

```
arr1 = np.array([1, 2, 3])
arr2 = np.array([[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]],
         [[7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]],
         [[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]]])

flatarray = arr2.flatten()
common_elements = np.intersect1d(arr1, flatarray)
a = len(common_elements)
print(a)
```

Now I want to find how to count the commom elements of 1D array vs a given [y][x][all elements] 3D array.

arr1=[1,2,3];

arr2[y][x][1,2,3,4,5];

Output: 3.

The thing is only to count with no loops but using functions, the same elements of arr1 (1D) vs the last dimension of arr2 (3D).

Thank you!

Comment: You're going to need to explain this more. What are the inputs? What are the outputs? Give some examples as well.

Comment: How did you solve the first problem?  Most general solutions in numpy work just as well with subarrays.

Comment: There is more context. Any idea? The thing is to count the common elements of 1D array vs the last dimension of the 3D array: for example [0][0][all elements].

Comment: I'm still lost with your notation. Are `x` and `y` just indexing variables? Does `[1,2,3,4,5]` mean the 3rd axis is of length 6 and you're looking at the last 5 elements? I assume you meant all the indices of the last axis, but I'm not sure why you wrote it as you did. I still recommend you provide example inputs and outputs. It would also help if you wrote a naive solution to describe what you're looking for, i.e. a nested loop solution.

Answer (score 0):

Considering x=0, y=0, you can use the same function to get the number of common elements.

```py
import numpy as np

arr1 = np.array([1, 2, 3])
arr2 = np.array([[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]],
                 [[7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]],
                 [[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]]])
x = 0
y = 0
print(len(np.intersect1d(arr1, arr2[y][x])))  # prints '3'
```

Comment: I gave more examples in here. As I know you have to resize the 1D to 3D? Check it better in here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76562017/how-to-find-the-number-of-common-elements-between-1d-array-and-specific-index-of