# How to find the number of common elements between 1D array and specific index of a 3D array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, arraylist

I have found the answer how to find the number of commom elements of 1D array vs all 3D array.

```
arr1 = np.array([1, 2, 3])
arr2 = np.array([
[[1, 6], [2, 7], [3, 8]],
[[4, 9], [5, 10], [6, 11]],
[[7, 12], [8, 13], [9, 14]]
]

flatarray = arr2.flatten()
common_elements = np.intersect1d(arr1, flatarray)
a = len(common_elements)
print(a)
```

Now I want to find how to count the commom elements of 1D array vs each last dimension of the 3D array.

For example just:

```
   [1, 2, 3]  vs  [2, 7] (part of the 3D without comparing with the rest of the 3D array)
```

Output: 1.

The thing is only to count with no loops but using functions, the same elements of arr1 (1D) vs the selected last dimension of arr2 (3D).

Thank you!

Comment: Please share your exact full problem, what exact full input(s) and what exact full expected output. [ask] and [mre]

Answer (score 1):

We could do:

```
np.isin(arr2, arr1).sum(axis=-1)
# array([[1, 1, 1],
#       [0, 0, 0],
#       [0, 0, 0]])
```

Answer (score 0):

To count the common elements between a 1D array (`arr1`) and each last dimension of a 3D array (`arr2`), you can use the `np.intersect1d` function along with the `axis` parameter of NumPy's array operations. Here's an example code snippet that achieves this:

```
import numpy as np

arr1 = np.array([1, 2, 3])
arr2 = np.array([
    [[1, 6], [2, 7], [3, 8]],
    [[4, 9], [5, 10], [6, 11]],
    [[7, 12], [8, 13], [9, 14]]
])

last_dim = arr2[..., -1]  # Select the last dimension of arr2

common_elements = np.intersect1d(arr1, last_dim)
count = common_elements.size

print(count)
```

In this example, `last_dim` is obtained by using the ellipsis ("...") to select all dimensions except the last one, and then indexing `-1` to select the last dimension only. The `np.intersect1d` function is then used to find the common elements between `arr1` and `last_dim`. Finally, the count of common elements is obtained by using the `size` property of the resulting array.

The output for the provided example will be:

```
1
```

This means that there is 1 common element between the 1D array `[1, 2, 3]` and the last dimension `[2, 7]` of the 3D array `arr2`.

Comment: Okay makes sense, but the only thing I dont get is how the [2,7] is selected? Writing the index instead of "...,"?

Comment: @Razor How do you know which the first two indexes of the 3D array? Do you wish to calculate it for all the sub-arrays?

Comment: Yes, otherwise is the same answer I found as well. As I posted without comparing with the rest of the 3D array. I mean for each [[1, 6], [2, 7], [3, 8]], and so on. Or maybe could be which sub-arrays dont have elements in common with the 1D array, could work too.